# Can't "render/not render" a4joutputpanel rendered="" "true/false" parameter by managed bean at JBoss Seam and Richfaces

Tags: ajax, richfaces, seam, ajax4jsf

I'm new on seam and richfaces. I want to hide/show a4joutputpanel by rendered="" "true/false" parameter by giving Managed Bean.But ı'm taking this exception:

**com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttributeException: /testscreen.xhtml
action="#{testBean.renderActive(true)}" Not a Valid Method Expression: #{testBean.renderActive(true)**}

Can anyone help me about that?

Here's my xhtml and managedbean codes:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{testBean.renderActive(true)}" reRender="MyPanel" value="Start" />

<a4j:outputPanel id="MyPanel">
<s:div rendered="#{testBean.renderProperty}">
........
</s:div>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

### ManagedBean

```
public void renderActive(Boolean rendeBoolean){
this.renderProperty=rendeBoolean; }

private Boolean renderProperty;

public Boolean getRenderProperty() {
return renderProperty;
}

public void setRenderProperty(Boolean renderProperty) {
this.renderProperty = renderProperty;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you would post the exception.

Comment: Hey Max; I'm taking this exception: **com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttributeException: /testscreen.xhtml action="#{testBean.renderActive(true)}" Not a Valid Method Expression: #{testBean.renderActive(true)}**

Answer (score 0):

`#{testBean.renderActive(true)}` is actually not a valid method expression in plain JSF EL because method expressions cannot have parameters.

It's valid with EL extension provided by jboss-el.jar, though.

Check if this jar is present in the application classpath, that is in the EAR or in WEB-INF/lib if you don't package the application as war. (see § *30.3.1 Packaging* in the reference documentation).

Comment: _is actually not a valid method expression in plain JSF EL because method expressions cannot have parameters._ Do you have any source ? Your are actually wrong, as you can pass parameters of any type through an EL expression.

Comment: Parameterized method call was introduced in Java EE 6. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gjddd/