# JSF Not a Valid Method Expression for Richfaces' a4j:ajax listener

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I tried to call static methods from my JSF by creating custom EL functions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080174/2073032). It worked fine for command links, actions, etc., but when I try to invoke a method in the Richfaces a4j:ajax below:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/taglib" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
   xmlns:utils="http://example.com/utils">
   ...
   <h:outputLink value="#">
           <a4j:ajax event="click" listener="#{reflectionUtils.setValue(entity,property,null)}" />
   ...
</ui:composition>
```

And the utils.taglib.xml file:

```
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
   <namespace>http://example.com/utils</namespace>

   <!-- ReflectionUtils -->
   <function>
      <function-name>setValue</function-name>
      <function-class>com.example.util.ReflectionUtils</function-class>
      <function-signature>void setValue(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)</function-signature>
   </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException with message: "/resources/facelets/input.xhtml @30,145 listener="#{utils:setValue(entity,property,null)}" Not a Valid Method Expression: #{utils:setValue(entity,property,null)}"
```

Looking through SO I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5484001/2073032) saying that with jboss-el.jar method calls with paremeters should work. Tried it, nothing changed.

Also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5273864/2073032) that says that web.xml should be configured to use Servlet 3.0. Tried that too, same result.

So I ask, is there a difference for a4j:ajax listener? How can I get it to work?

Comment: Maybe it is not listener but action method. What about use it with `a4j:commandLink`?

Comment: Thanks, @VasilLukach! Works nicely. Please, post the suggestion as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method you used look like action method, not as a listener method. You can use it with `a4j:commandLink`.